# Trying to improve my understanding why answers get deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

First of all, this is neither a rant nor an approach to get the answer undeleted, I am willing to accept downvotes on this question.
I have to improve my understanding why answers get deleted on meta.
I got [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275969/1699210) deleted, and I am trying to understand which reason from the help is the one fitting here.

- commentary on the question or other answers
- asking another, different question
- “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
- exact duplicates of other answers
- barely more than a link to an external site
- not even a partial answer to the actual question

Should it have been a comment, did it not try to answer the question?
In my understanding meta is the democratic place to create common opinion, so wrong answers or answers against the mainstream should be downvoted and would be part of finding the common opinion.

Comment: Voted to undelete. Your question, however, is somewhat site specific; each community will have their own (subjective) rules as to what goes and what stays.

Comment: I've also left a comment on the question, hopefully that'll get the deleted answer another undelete vote.

Comment: Your answer was undeleted! Be the proud owner of a -19 answer :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman as I stated it was not an approach to get the answer undeleted, I was asking for clarification with concern on democracy on a felt emotive thread.

Comment: @bummi: I agree. That's why I answered too. It might be useful to you and others to see the actual post which is discussed, including all comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that answer shouldn't be deleted. It is on-topic, answers the question, and not commentary worthy.

Okay, people disagree, but I don't think that is a valid reason to delete an answer, especially on meta.

Also, see the list of reasons to delete an answer (from the help, which is the same on Meta as on SO). Your answer doesn't fit these rules:

> - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> - The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.

Your deleted answer (for people not having 10K):

> Because it is an answer to the question `Any useful information or links to Git tutorials are also welcome!`. It's the question asking for a recommendation.

I voted to undelete.